# pass the class name in view (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, view

At view pass variables @stalytd:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/table", :locals => {:@number => "10 этаж", :@apartmentq => @apartment10, :apartment => @apartment, :stalytd =>@stalytd} %>
```

How to use it to assign a value to a variable name in the partial, the class?

```
<table id="tabletd" class="@stalytd">
```

I need to paint the cells that are filled with data about the customer, in red.

```
@fio=apartment.f_buyer
    @ifo=apartment.i_buyer

    if @fio != nil 
        elsif @ifo != ""
    then 
        @stalytd=redcolor
    else
        @stalytd=greencolor
   end
```

Comment: I don't know how do it (

Answer (score 0):

Use your variable like this:-

```
<%= @stalytd =%>
```

for example

```
<table id="tabletd" class="<%= @stalytd =%>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="tabletd" class="<%= @stalytd %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table id="tabletd" class="<%=stalytd %>">
```

Comment: It's assigns class="@stalytd", not value

Comment: Sorry, in your `partial`, it should be `class="<%=stalytd %>"` without "@"